# how to use solidity contracts in web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js

alright, so I have the following basic contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Program {
    function get() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

and I have compiled it successfully by using solc and at my bin folder I have a .bin & .abi file. great, but how can I use the contract?

I tried to do it with web3.js, but apparently to get access to contracts you have to use some sort of address. I don't have anything like that. I have just compiled my solidity contract and I haven't deployed it to anywhere. if possible I would like to deploy it to my `localhost`, since I'm just messing around, I'm not building a real app.

If possible I would like a simple JavaScript script that runs some functions in a compiled contract.

I know Remix IDE is a thing, but I want to do work with Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the compiled contract to a local EVM emulator such as Hardhat or Ganache.

The deployment process "uploads" the bytecode to an address, which you can pass (along with the contract ABI) to your JS app.